# Styling a famo.us InputSurface's placeholder text?

Tags: famo.us

Do [famo.us](http://famo.us) surface have any support for pseudo CSS selectors? Specifically, I'm trying to style the placeholder text on an *InputSurface*. Any way of doing this without giving it a class and using CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Famo.us at this time has not created any special pseudo-element styling helper. Famo.us supports the changing of styles through `setProperties` of the Surface object.

Surfaces in version 0.3.0 also support the attributes option.  Add an attribute for the `placeholder` as shown in the code below.

**[Example of working code here](http://jsbin.com/boxasu/1/edit?js,output)**

```js
  var surface = new InputSurface({
    size: [200, true],
    content: '',
    attributes: {
      placeholder: 'Enter Something'
    }
  });
```

You could also use the setAttributes method:

```js
  var surface = new InputSurface({
    size: [200, true],
    content: ''
  });

  surface.setAttributes({ placeholder: 'Enter Something'});
  surface.setProperties({borderColor:'red'});
```

Comment: Read your question too fast, I will edit with respect to styling the `pseudo CSS`